# Nested StackLayout does not render within DataTemplate

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have observed that a nested StackLayout does not render completely within a DataTemplate.

Specifically, only name, labor, and LaborCost gets rendered. All other values are ignored.

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Services}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="Labor:" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding LaborCost}" />
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="Materials:" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Materials, Converter={StaticResource MaterialsToCostConverter}}" />
                            </StackLayout>

                            <Label Text="{Binding Description}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: are you sure it's not a problem with your converter?

Comment: I commented out that line. I still observe the same issue.

Comment: If you replace it with a simple Text binding does it work?  It's not clear exactly what the issue you're seeing is.  Does the "Materials" label render correctly?  It might be helpful if you posted a screencap of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Added following attribute to ListView:

> HasUnevenRows="True"